# Верстка дивов у сайта

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Добрый день! При верстке сайта обнаружился странный недочет вывода товаров в div'e. Причем в одном случае выводится нормально товар (плиткой), в другом скачет между строками. Помогите!

Для начала приведу код css отвечающего за верстку тегов div:

```
.col { float: left; margin-right: 20px }
.col_13 { width: 300px }
.col_14 { width: 220px }
.col_15 { width: 400px }
.col_16 { width: 140px }
.col_23 { width: 620px }

.product_gallery {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    text-align: center
}

.product_gallery img {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.product_gallery h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.product_gallery .product_price {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 700
}

#content {
    float: right;
    width: 700px;
    width: 700px;
    padding: 20px 10px 20px;
}
```

Теперь картинка и html-код который корретно выводит плиткой товары:
[image]

```
    <div id="content">
      <div id="pagginator">         
      <center><span id='pagginator2'> 1 </span></center>
      </div>

      <h2>Компьютеры</h2>

      <div class="col col_14 product_gallery">       
       <a href="productdetail.php?id=16"><img src="images/product/17.png" alt="Компьютер-3" /></a>
       <h3>Компьютер-3</h3>
       <p class="product_price">17400 руб.</p>
       <a href="shoppingcart.php?operation=add&id=16" class="add_to_cart">В корзину</a>
      </div>  

      <div class="col col_14 product_gallery"> 
      <a href="productdetail.php?id=17"><img src="images/product/18.png" alt="Компьютер-4" /></a>
      <h3>Компьютер-4</h3>
      <p class="product_price">15100 руб.</p>
      <a href="shoppingcart.php?operation=add&id=17" class="add_to_cart">В корзину</a>
      </div>  

      <div class="col col_14 product_gallery no_margin_right">               
      <a href="productdetail.php?id=14"><img src="images/product/15.png" alt="Компьютер1" /></a>
      <h3>Компьютер1</h3>
      <p class="product_price">18099 руб.</p>
      <a href="shoppingcart.php?operation=add&id=14" class="add_to_cart">В корзину</a>
      </div>  

      <div class="col col_14 product_gallery">       
      <a href="productdetail.php?id=15"><img src="images/product/16.png" alt="Компьютер2" /></a>
      <h3>Компьютер2</h3>
      <p class="product_price">21500 руб.</p>
      <a href="shoppingcart.php?operation=add&id=15" class="add_to_cart">В корзину</a>
      </div>  
</div>
```

Теперь привожу картинку и код неккоректного вывода товаров на экран (вариант 1), где
второй ряд товаров "скачет" и начинает со второй позиции:

[image]

```
<div id="content">

              <div id="pagginator">         
               <center>
               <a href="/web_shop/index.php?page=1&cat=13">1</a> <span id='pagginator2'> 2 </span>               
               </center>
          </div>

              <h2>Прочее</h2>

                  <div class="col col_14 product_gallery">       
                  <a href="productdetail.php?id=19"><img src="images/product/20a.jpg" alt="Розетка стандартная" /></a>
                  <h3>Розетка стандартная</h3>
                  <p class="product_price">250 руб.</p>
                  <a href="shoppingcart.php?operation=add&id=19" class="add_to_cart">В корзину</a>
                 </div>  

                  <div class="col col_14 product_gallery">       
                  <a href="productdetail.php?id=8"><img src="images/product/08.jpg" alt="Степлер офисный" /></a>
                  <h3>Степлер офисный</h3>
                  <p class="product_price">420 руб.</p>
                  <a href="shoppingcart.php?operation=add&id=8" class="add_to_cart">В корзину</a>
                 </div>  

                 <div class="col col_14 product_gallery no_margin_right">        
                  <a href="productdetail.php?id=7"><img src="images/product/07.jpg" alt="Сувенир "Триколор"" /></a>
                  <h3>Сувенир "Триколор"</h3>
                  <p class="product_price">950 руб.</p>
                  <a href="shoppingcart.php?operation=add&id=7" class="add_to_cart">В корзину</a>
                 </div>  

                 <div class="col col_14 product_gallery">        
                  <a href="productdetail.php?id=4"><img src="images/product/04.jpg" alt="Туфли женские" /></a>
                  <h3>Туфли женские</h3>
                  <p class="product_price">700 руб.</p>
                  <a href="shoppingcart.php?operation=add&id=4" class="add_to_cart">В корзину</a>
                 </div>  

</div>
```

И последний скрин и код, некорректного вывода товаров на экран браузера, где все перекосило в конец:

[image]

```
<div id="content">

              <div id="pagginator">         
              <center>
              <span id='pagginator2'> 1 </span>               <br><a href="add_good.php" class="add_good">Добавить товар</a><br> 
              </center>
              </div><h2>Компьютеры</h2>
                                  <div class="col col_14 product_gallery"> 


                  <a href="productdetail.php?id=42"><img src="images/product/00.jpg" alt="комп5" /></a>
                  <h3>комп5</h3>
                  <p class="product_price">30000 руб.</p>
                  <!--<a href="shoppingcart.php?operation=add&id=" class="add_to_cart">В корзину</a>--> 
                  <a href=edit_good.php?id=&cat=7 class="edit_good">Изменить товар</a><br>
                  <a href=admin.php?operation=delete&id=&cat=7 class="delete_good">Удалить товар</a>
                 </div>  
                                      <div class="col col_14 product_gallery"> 


                  <a href="productdetail.php?id=16"><img src="images/product/17.png" alt="Компьютер-3" /></a>
                  <h3>Компьютер-3</h3>
                  <p class="product_price">17400 руб.</p>
                  <!--<a href="shoppingcart.php?operation=add&id=" class="add_to_cart">В корзину</a>--> 
                  <a href=edit_good.php?id=&cat=7 class="edit_good">Изменить товар</a><br>
                  <a href=admin.php?operation=delete&id=&cat=7 class="delete_good">Удалить товар</a>
                 </div>  
                                     <div class="col col_14 product_gallery no_margin_right">



                  <a href="productdetail.php?id=17"><img src="images/product/18.png" alt="Компьютер-4" /></a>
                  <h3>Компьютер-4</h3>
                  <p class="product_price">15100 руб.</p>
                  <!--<a href="shoppingcart.php?operation=add&id=" class="add_to_cart">В корзину</a>--> 
                  <a href=edit_good.php?id=&cat=7 class="edit_good">Изменить товар</a><br>
                  <a href=admin.php?operation=delete&id=&cat=7 class="delete_good">Удалить товар</a>
                 </div>  
                                      <div class="col col_14 product_gallery"> 


                  <a href="productdetail.php?id=14"><img src="images/product/15.png" alt="Компьютер1" /></a>
                  <h3>Компьютер1</h3>
                  <p class="product_price">18099 руб.</p>
                  <!--<a href="shoppingcart.php?operation=add&id=" class="add_to_cart">В корзину</a>--> 
                  <a href=edit_good.php?id=&cat=7 class="edit_good">Изменить товар</a><br>
                  <a href=admin.php?operation=delete&id=&cat=7 class="delete_good">Удалить товар</a>
                 </div>  
                                      <div class="col col_14 product_gallery"> 


                  <a href="productdetail.php?id=15"><img src="images/product/16.png" alt="Компьютер2" /></a>
                  <h3>Компьютер2</h3>
                  <p class="product_price">21500 руб.</p>
                  <!--<a href="shoppingcart.php?operation=add&id=" class="add_to_cart">В корзину</a>--> 
                  <a href=edit_good.php?id=&cat=7 class="edit_good">Изменить товар</a><br>
                  <a href=admin.php?operation=delete&id=&cat=7 class="delete_good">Удалить товар</a>
                 </div>  
</div>
```

Кто-нибудь из опытных верстальщиков сайтов может сказать в чем тут подвох. Почему в одном случае вывод идет нормально, а в других некорректно? Подскажите...

Comment: разная высота дивов - в этом проблема

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   .col { display: inline-block; 
          vertical-align: top; 
          margin: 0 15px 15px 0; 
    }
```

Comment: все стало нормально опять. Спасибо большое, а то я в css слаб еще!

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно чтобы каждый блок с товаром был по высоте одинакового размера, тогда блоки будут правильно выстраиваться, либо вместо `float: left` для блоков с товарами использовать `display: inline-block` и так же выровнять их по верху `vertical-align: top` относительно друг друга. Правда если блоки будут `display: inline-block`, то у них добавится дополнительный отступ справа. Здесь  написано как вылечить такой недуг [Кроссбраузерный `inline-block`](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117109/).